# Problemas com conexão PHP -> MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Erro**

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/1130): Host '10.1.1.25' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a1570220/public_html/register.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/a1570220/public_html/register.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a1570220/public_html/register.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a1570220/public_html/register.php on line 10
>
> {"success":true}

**Aqui o código:**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("confidencial", "confidencial", "confidencial", "confidencial");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (email, senha) VALUES (?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $email, $senha);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

*Onde diz confidencial são os dados privados do meu db por isso troquei.*

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Você instalou o MySQL à parte ou está usando um pacote como Xampp, Wampp? Se instalou à parte, dá uma olhada no arquivo de configuração "my.cfg" do MySQL e procure por "bind address", se estiver 127.0.0.1 troque por 0.0.0.0 e tente novamente.

Answer (score 4):

O primeiro erro, **HY000/1130** é o que interessa no caso:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/1130): Host '10.1.1.25' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a1570220/public_html/register.php on line 2

Isso significa que **o host que você está usando para a conexão** não está autorizado a acessar o DB.

Em outras palavras, **mesmo que o usuário e a senha estejam certos**, é necessário que no MySQL esse usuário tenha permissão para acessar do IP que você está usando.

Para ver as permissões do user desejado pode fazer assim:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR nomeDoUser@ipOuNomeDoHost;
```

Note que o IP que você está usando **não necessariamente é o da máquina onde sai a aplicação**, e sim o último do roteamento final, se for um NAT, Docker, virtualização ou qualquer coisa que modifique o IP para o MySQL. Para isto, verifique no destino final o IP que está chegando até a máquina (IP ou nome do host).

Por exemplo, ao criar um usuário com essa linha:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' ...
```

você está permitindo que o usuário `jeffrey` só se conecte localmente, e isto se `localhost` for um nome válido localmente. Nem sempre é.

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'%' ...
```

aqui já está usando o "coringa" `%`, que permite acesso de qualquer host, **o que normalmente não é desejável se uma permissão mais restrita resolver**, em especial numa rede com IPs fixos (como numa hospedagem, se o DB só for acessado por uma aplicação da mesma rede).

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'200.200.200.1' ...
```

Finalmente, assim você definiu um IP único para acesso.

**Se o usuário já foi criado**, você pode alterar o campo `host` na tabela de usuários do MySQL (ou preferencialmente usando o comando específico de alteração), para evitar ter que criar um usuário novo para ter acesso.

Além do usuário precisar do acesso acima, é necessário ajustar o acesso do usuário para as tabelas. Por exemplo:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuário'@'%';
```

Você pode dar vários `GRANT`s para IPs diferentes com o mesmo usuário, se quiser. Pode inclusive dar permissões que mudam conforme o IP usado.

**Atenção:**

- normalmente você não deve usar a linha acima exatamente como está.

  `ALL PRIVILEGES` normalmente é muito privilégio para um usuário de sistema normal. O ideal é permitir apenas o mínimo necessário, por exemplo apenas `SELECT`, `INSERT` etc, ou seja, apenas o que for usado;

  `ON *.*` está dando acesso a todas as tabelas e bancos, no caso você deve por apenas o que for necessário. É melhor algo como: ON `db_especifico.* TO...`
- você precisa executar o comando acima como administrador.

Para efetivar a mudança acima, finalmente execute

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

para atualizar as credenciais do MySQL.

Quanto aos erros seguintes, São basicamente consequência do problema inicial. Estão faltando na sua aplicação as verificações antes de fazer a *query* para saber se cada comando anterior foi executado com sucesso.

Comment: Mano, fiz isso e deu isso aqui #1045 - Access denied for user 'confidencial'@'localhost' (using password: YES) .

Comment: Access denied é um erro diferente do da pergunta. Pode ser erro nos privilégios que deu para o IP específico (por exemplo, faltando nas tabelas). De qualquer forma, isso é o caso de pesquisar em uma pergunta específica do 1045.

Comment: Verifique na tabela `users` do db `mysql` se o `%` realmente esta no "host" do usuário.